# Labeled Matrix positioning problem

Tags: matrices, gauss

So I am writing a transition matrix for markov chains using the `gauss` package. Here's what I have:

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{gauss}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{align*}
        T\left(s, a_1, s^\prime\right) &= 
            \begin{bmatrix}
            0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0.1 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}\\
        T\left(s, a_1, s^\prime\right) &= 
        \begin{gmatrix}[b]
            \mathllap{S_1\quad} 0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0\\
            \mathllap{S_2\quad} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
            \mathllap{S_3\quad} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0.1 \\
            \mathllap{S_4\quad} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            \mathllap{S_5\quad} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\colops
            \def\colmultlabel#1{\makebox[1.2em]{$#1$}}
            \mult0{S_1}
            \mult1{S_2}
            \mult2{S_3}
            \mult3{S_4}
            \mult4{S_5}
        \end{gmatrix}\\
        T\left(s, a_1, s^\prime\right) &= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
            0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0.1 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I realized that the `gmatrix` outputs a normal matrix placed like a normal matrix from `amsmath`, but the problem is that the labels do not get factored in. That is, the row and column labels do not create space for it to be separated from the equals sign on its line or the equation above.

How to fix it?

Comment: Is there a reason for writing `^\prime` when `'` creates the *identical output* with much less input effort?

Comment: From my memory, writing `\prime` gave me a bigger sign, and it wasn’t positioned correctly.

Comment: I did *not* ask you why you don't write `\prime` in the document. I asked you why you would input `^\prime` -- which is definitely not the same as `\prime` -- given that `'` creates the identical output but does so with much less input effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just insert some horizontal space.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{gauss}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{align*}
        T\left(s, a_1, s^\prime\right) &= 
            \begin{bmatrix}
            0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0.1 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}\\
        T\left(s, a_1, s^\prime\right) &=\;\quad
        \begin{gmatrix}[b]
            \mathllap{S_1\quad} 0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0\\
            \mathllap{S_2\quad} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
            \mathllap{S_3\quad} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0.1 \\
            \mathllap{S_4\quad} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            \mathllap{S_5\quad} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\colops
            \def\colmultlabel#1{\makebox[1.2em]{$#1$}}
            \mult0{S_1}
            \mult1{S_2}
            \mult2{S_3}
            \mult3{S_4}
            \mult4{S_5}
        \end{gmatrix}\\
        T\left(s, a_1, s^\prime\right) &= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
            0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0.1 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you want this output I recommend `nicematrix`, with which you can add the `S_i` automatically.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{align*}
        T\left(s, a_1, s^\prime\right) &= 
            \begin{bmatrix}
            0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0.1 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}\\
        T\left(s, a_1, s^\prime\right) &=
        \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col,
    code-for-first-row = S_{\number\value{jCol}},
    code-for-first-col = S_{\number\value{iRow}}
    ]
            & & & & &  \\ 
            & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0\\
            & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
            & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0.1 \\
            & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
        \end{bNiceMatrix}\\
        T\left(s, a_1, s^\prime\right) &= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
            0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0.1 \\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your spacing command really does a good job of properly spacing it out! Thank you so much!

Comment: I was wondering if there is a “general” command that can space out as properly as if I wrote a `bmatrix` instead of a makeshift command like what you wrote.

Comment: @Superman Naively it should be `\hphantom{S_1\quad}` but this does not yield an appealing result. I added a second possibility with which you do not have to worry about any of this.

Comment: Speaking of `nicematrix`, when writing out the labels, how come we have an extra row and column that’s empty?

Comment: @Superman These are the cells that are outside of the matrix. That is, `first-row,first-col,` indicates that the first row and columns are outside of the matrix. They get automatically filled with `S_{\number\value{jCol}}` and `S_{\number\value{iRowl}}`, respectively, due to `code-for-first-row` and `code-for-first-col`

Comment: Ok got it, thank you!

Comment: @Superman Yes, just drop `code-for-first-row = S_{\number\value{jCol}},
    code-for-first-col = S_{\number\value{iRow}}` and put the letters in the empty cells.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous question because I was going to look for the documentation, but thank you for telling me how to write custom labels!